# AMD Catalyst 11.7 with external monitor

Tags: 11.04, video, ati, fglrx, external-monitor

Just installed Catalyst 11.7
At times overheating when in games and external monitor works only in mirror mode.

When I try to change monitor settings, it completely hangs the system. After reboot shows error, something like "error on line 1 on symbol 1" or kind of that. With open-source drivers everything were fine, but with catalyst external monitor works only in mirror mode.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Radeon HD5xxx or newer, then I would suggest you use the open driver. AMD has people working full time on it and in my experience, it's already much faster and more stable than the proprietary one. So without knowing why you installed the proprietary driver in the first place, I would say the answer is to uninstall Catalyst.

Only AMD can fix problems with the proprietary drivers. Noone else.

Comment: I used open drivers before, everything went fine, except playing games. With my open driver Heroes Of Newerth was lagging, while catalyst get much better performance in that, even better than my home PC with Win XP and NVidia 512MB card. This time AMD get much better support for performance, but also have some bugs. Like this one, I described. If this problem can be fixed only by AMD, I'll wait until they fix it. Thanks.